# Efficiently retrieving stats for all GitHub Commits

Tags: github-api

Is there a more efficient way of getting the count of additions/deletions related to a commit than looping through every single commit and calling the:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha
```

(https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)

Just to get the:

```
"stats": {
   "additions": 104,
   "deletions": 4,
   "total": 108
},
```

Data?

Unfortunately the commits endpoint:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

Contains a lot of data about each commit but not this detail which means a huge number of additional API calls to get it.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you need multiple GitHub API query, check if **[GraphQL](http://graphql.org/)** ([introduced by GitHub last Sept. 2016](http://githubengineering.com/the-github-graphql-api/)) could allow you to get all those commits in *one* query.

You can see [examples here](https://github.com/github/github-graphql-rails-example) and apply to [GitHub GraphQL early access](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/), but that sees to be the only way to get:

- all stats from all commits (and *only* the stats)
- in one query

Comment: VonC thanks - I will take a look, but it looks like it is in preview and we really need something which is in production I think. I am still assuming then that this is not possible with the current GitHub API.

Comment: @chrisb Yes, it does not seem possible at the moment with the current GitHub API indeed.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to get [commit stats](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/commit/#fields) (`additions`, `deletions` & `changedFiles` count) using the [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) :

To get commit stats for the 100 first commit on the default branch :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "google", name: "gson") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      name
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          id
          history(first: 100) {
            nodes {
              oid
              message
              additions
              deletions
              changedFiles
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22google%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22gson%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20defaultBranchRef%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20additions%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20deletions%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20changedFiles%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

To get commit stats for the first 10 branches, for the 100 first commits of each one of these branches:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "google", name: "gson") {
    refs(first: 10, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              id
              history(first: 100) {
                nodes {
                  oid
                  message
                  additions
                  deletions
                  changedFiles
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22google%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22gson%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs(first%3A%2010%2C%20refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20additions%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20deletions%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20changedFiles%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)