# Github API: GET releases for all repos within a given org

Tags: github-api

I am trying to build a program that fetches the releases for every repository within an org. There could be one, a few, or a lot of repos within the org. What is the best way to achieve this through the GitHub API?

I see that individual repos have a releases API (https://api.github.com/repos/:org/:repo/releases), but I would like to be able to retrieve a consolidated list for the entire org.

Is it possible to do this in one request, or do I need to first fetch all repos for the org (https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos), and then run a batch of requests against each repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this in one request, or do I need to first fetch all repos for the org (https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos), and then run a batch of requests against each repo?

The latter (and you have to [deal with pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/), if there are too many repos in an org)

I [mentioned before GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709725/6309) (to be able to do your query in one operation), but it is still an early access preview.